# How to use useMemo in this example?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-usememo

I'm struggling with problem chaning `const variable` to const with useMemo. I tried some example from docs and some tutorials and nothing worked for me. This have to be easy...

```
const bottomSheetOptions: BottomSheetAction[] = [
    {
      label:
        t('kebabMenu.send') +
        (count > 1 ? t('kebabMenu.documents', { count }) : ''),
      icon: <SendIcon />,
      state: sendVisible,
      dismiss: () => showSendAlert(),
      onClick: () => showSendAlert(),
      alertType: 'sendInvoice',
      disabled: count > 0,
      visible: documentType === 'sales'
    },
    {
      label: t('kebabMenu.download'),
      icon: <DownloadIcon />,
      state: downloadVisible,
      dismiss: () => showDownloadDocumentsModal(),
      onClick: () => showDownloadDocumentsModal(),
      alertType: 'download',
      disabled: true,
      visible: true
    }
  ];
```

So i'm tried this but it gives me error

```
const bottomSheetOptions: BottomSheetAction[] = useMemo(() => [[
    {
      label:
        t('kebabMenu.send') +
        (count > 1 ? t('kebabMenu.documents', { count }) : ''),
      icon: <SendIcon />,
      state: sendVisible,
      dismiss: () => showSendAlert(),
      onClick: () => showSendAlert(),
      alertType: 'sendInvoice',
      disabled: count > 0,
      visible: documentType === 'sales'
    },
    {
      label: t('kebabMenu.download'),
      icon: <DownloadIcon />,
      state: downloadVisible,
      dismiss: () => showDownloadDocumentsModal(),
      onClick: () => showDownloadDocumentsModal(),
      alertType: 'download',
      disabled: true,
      visible: true
    }
  ]], [documentType, downloadVisible, sendVisible, showDownloadDocumentsModal, showSendAlert])
```

Error:

```
Type '{ label: string; icon: Element; state: boolean; dismiss: () => void; onClick: () => void; alertType: string; disabled: boolean; visible: boolean; }[][]' is not assignable to type 'BottomSheetAction[]'.
  Type '{ label: string; icon: Element; state: boolean; dismiss: () => void; onClick: () => void; alertType: string; disabled: boolean; visible: boolean; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'BottomSheetAction': label, icon, state, dismiss, and 4 more.
```

---EDIT---
Adding type of array BottomSheetAction

```
export type BottomSheetAction = {
  label: string;
  icon: React.ReactNode;
  state: boolean;
  dismiss: () => void;
  onClick: () => void;
  alertType: 'download' | 'sendInvoice';
  disabled: boolean;
  visible: boolean;
};
```

Comment: You're doing this: `useMemo(() => [[` (note the two square brackets), creating an array of array of `BottomSheetAction`, and trying to assign it to an array of the same type. Ie. `BottomSheetAction[][]` to `BottomSheetAction[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "useMemo" attempt you are returning an array in an array. I don't have the `BottomSheetAction` type, but try replacing the outer square bracket with round ones, i.e.:

```
const bottomSheetOptions: BottomSheetAction[] = useMemo(() => [
    {
      label:
        t('kebabMenu.send') +
        (count > 1 ? t('kebabMenu.documents', { count }) : ''),
      icon: <SendIcon />,
      state: sendVisible,
      dismiss: () => showSendAlert(),
      onClick: () => showSendAlert(),
      alertType: 'sendInvoice',
      disabled: count > 0,
      visible: documentType === 'sales'
    },
    {
      label: t('kebabMenu.download'),
      icon: <DownloadIcon />,
      state: downloadVisible,
      dismiss: () => showDownloadDocumentsModal(),
      onClick: () => showDownloadDocumentsModal(),
      alertType: 'download',
      disabled: true,
      visible: true
    }
  ], [documentType, downloadVisible, sendVisible, showDownloadDocumentsModal, showSendAlert])
```

Comment: Those round brackets doesn't matter but clue was that I was doing double square brackets `[[]]`

Comment: You are correct, it comes from my habbit when return an object `{ ... }`instead of array `[ ... ]`

Answer (score 1):

I think that the type of `bottomSheetOptions` which is `BottomSheetAction[]` doesn't match what you return inside the `useMemo` callback.

I think that you are returning an array which contains a single array which contains items of type `BottomSheetAction`.

Could you try changing `[[` to `[` and `]]` to `]`?